# Get current path and access folders

Tags: python

I'm currently writing a script that needs access to a network folder. I'm using PowerShell instead of CMD because CMD can't access network drives.

My script needs to get the location from where the PowerShell is ran (the script .py is also in this location). I also need to access other subdirectories in that folder, e.g.:

powershell/script path = \network\map

let python access that location + \input

Comment: Please add a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Sach there isn't really any code I need to show for this. I'm just not sure how to do it

Answer (score 0):

@Frankicks. In your script, you can get current (actual) absolute path by doing the following (for example):

```
import os

# current directory:
curdir = os.getcwd()
print(curdir)
# absolute path of the present script file
filepath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
print(filepath)
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I access folders from this path? so: current_path\folder1\folder2

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

complete_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Documents/storage/2018-report.xlsx")
print(complete_path)
```

> /Users/username/Documents/storage/2018-report.xlsx